# Broken legs in Pose Mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

I'm sure this is a fairly common issue, but I have yet to find a similar question to my plight- and I am also extremely new. So I have this model I made entirely in edit mode, and I rigged it using the rigify addon with the metahuman option. I connected the rig to the model with the automatic weight option. Everything works perfectly, even the fingers, but the legs for some reason distort and break whenever I try to pose them. As you can see, the model rig in resting position...
[image: Model in resting position]

...And then after that, the model with the leg posed.
[image: Second model image]

Is this an issue with my mesh, my rig, or maybe my weighting? It's not *too* urgent, but I would like to see it resolved.

Comment: yes you need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode

Comment: It's worth trying to move the armature knee joint forward slightly. It looks as if the thigh and shin bones are exactly in line at the moment which can confuse Rigify.The same applies to the elbow joint.   That should be moved back slightly so that the lower and upper arm bones aren't exactly in line.